# Undefined property: Index::$session

Tags: php, codeigniter

How Can I Solve the issue When I am running this code I am getting the following error I have already loaded session library still i am getting this error
This is my controller

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();        
}
public function index() {
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('form', 'url');
    $this->load->library('session');
}
public function process() {     
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    if (!$result) {
        $msg = '<font color=red>Invalid username and/or password.</font><br />';
        $this->load->view(base_url().'index',$msg);
    } else {
        if ($_SESSION['utype'] == 2 || $_SESSION['utype'] == 1) {
            redirect(base_url() . 'admin/dashboard');
        }
        if ($_SESSION['utype'] == 3 && !empty($_POST['urlValue'])) {
            redirect($_POST['urlValue']);
        }
        if (empty($_POST['urlValue'])) {
            redirect('/');
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
   public function validate() { 
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('email'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));            
    $pwd = base64_encode($password); 
    $this->db->where('email', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $pwd);      
    $query = $this->db->get('adduser');
    $row = $query->row();

    if (count($row) > 0) {           
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
            'uid' => $row->id,
            'uname' => $row->firstname,
            'utype' => $row->usertype,
            'uemail' => $row->email,
            'validated' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return $row;
    }      
    return $row;
}
```

I am getting this problem:

```
 Severity: Notice
 Message: Undefined property: Index::$session
 Filename: core/Model.php
 Line Number: 77
 Backtrace:
 File: D:\xampp\htdocs\savepaise\application\models\Login_model.php
 Line: 42
 Function: __get
 File: D:\xampp\htdocs\savepaise\application\controllers\Index.php
 Line: 31
 Function: validate
 File: D:\xampp\htdocs\savepaise\index.php
 Line: 315
 Function: require_once
 Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object in 
 D:\xampp\htdocs\savepaise\application\models\Login_model.php on line 42
   A PHP Error was encountered
 Severity: Error
 Message: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object
 Filename: models/Login_model.php
 Line Number: 42
```

Comment: i think you need to load all library inside the controller  constructor function not in index function

Comment: Add session library in autoload.php

Comment: Edit format of your post. title of your question in too long, and code's of question is not correct. and text of your question is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to load `all library` inside the `controller` `constructor` function not only in `index function`

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('form', 'url');
    $this->load->library('session');        
}
```

**Update 1 :** you can use autoload like this

Go to `applications/config/autoload.php` and in there you can edit what you need.

They are in arrays and seperated by packages, libraries, helpers, config, languages and models.

Example

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');

$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'html', 'form');
```

Comment: Thanks JYoThI, after adding this $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session'); Now it is working

Comment: glad to help you @brod

Comment: Thank you very much JYoThI.

Comment: are u from andhra?

Comment: i'm from chennai

Comment: i'm from andhra , nice to meet you

Comment: yeah same here :)